# ReactNative app crashes only if running in Release mode

Tags: react-native

I'm building this app in RN and after upgrading to 0.49, it started crashing only when in "release" mode. It crashes right after it starts. It took me awhile to even trace down the crash point because my crash reporter (bugsnag) isn't even triggering.

I set the scheme in xcode to "release" and I was finally able to reproduce the crash with a tethered device.

The output is:

```
43  JavaScriptCore                      0x00000001880011ac _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 316
44  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018836a558 JSEvaluateScript +2017-10-15 02:54:24.331 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.View.propTypes.style')
B56
INFO : BSG_KSCrashReport.c (2157): void bsg_kscrashreport_writeStandardReport(BSG_KSCrash_Context *const, const char *const): Writing crash report to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00FD4F8E-DFF5-4166-982B-0D4AB56048DE/Library/Caches/KSCrashReports/GP/GP-CrashReport-0659B2B2-1DB4-48B9-BDDB-5EC72DE8B201.json
2017-10-15 02:54:24.354 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.View.propTypes.style')
2017-10-15 02:54:24.357 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
INFO : BSG_KSCrashReport.c (2157): void bsg_kscrashreport_writeStandardReport(BSG_KSCrash_Context *const, const char *const): Writing crash report to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00FD4F8E-DFF5-4166-982B-0D4AB56048DE/Library/Caches/KSCrashReports/GP/GP-CrashReport-9288B937-E697-4571-AE3D-5377FB7EABAE.json
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I suspect it's being caused by the bundler.. Could be Babel or something else. I've tracked down any references to "*.propTypes.style" and commented them out, thinking it'd be those, but that didn't change the result. It still crashes.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too suffered from this problem.  The issue ended up being that some of the components I used were still using:

```
View.PropTypes.style
```

Unfortunately had to revert back to react-native 48.4 until the respective packages were updated.

In my case it was react-native-facebook-login.

Try searching your node modules to find the specific components using the above and inform the dev that it needs to be updated to be compatible with 0.49.x

Comment: This was it. One of my libs was still doing this, and for some reason it wasn't failing in debug mode.

Comment: In my case it was react-native-credit-card-input wasted a lot of time to figure this out! :(

Answer (score 5):

Try to

1) run your app in debug mode

2) uncheck 'JS Dev Mode' in Dev Settings

3) Reload app

you will see some errors related to propTypes.

I had a similar issue. by disabling JS Dev Mode I figured out my packages are using `View.PropTypes.style`.

In another similar issue, it was from fabric crashlytics. I changed it's version and problem solved.

Comment: Thank you so much, i was stuck with the error from last 20 hrs, though the error was not related to proptypes but got it with your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to check log where it is breaking with `adb log` in simulator

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, I can see 2 problems:

- You use a third party module using ...View.propTypes. It'll not crash in debug mode, but it'll display a red screen during the launch
- The module name you use, is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

View.proptypes is deprecated in latest react 
  native.use ViewPropTypes instead of  View.proptypes.

```
import {ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
  styles: PropTypes.shape({
    view: ViewPropTypes.style,
    })
```